# From a set of columns with true/false values, say which column has a True value

Tags: pandas

I have a df with with several columns which have only True/False values.
I want to create another column whose value will tell me which column has a `True` value.
HEre's an example:

| index | bol_1 | bol_2 | bol_3 | criteria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | False | False | `bol_1` |
| 2 | False | True | False | `bol_2` |
| 3 | True | True | False | [`bol_1`, `bol_2`] |

My objective is to know which rows have True values(at least 1), and which columns are responsible for those True values. I want to be able to some basic statistics on this new column, e.g. for how many rows is bol_1 the unique column to have a True values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for boolean columns, convert columns names to array and in list comprehension filter `True`s values:

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes(bool)
cols = df1.columns.to_numpy()

df['criteria'] = [list(cols[x]) for x in df1.to_numpy()]

print (df)
   bol_1  bol_2  bol_3        criteria
1   True  False  False         [bol_1]
2  False   True  False         [bol_2]
3   True   True  False  [bol_1, bol_2]
```

If performance is not important use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['criteria'] = df1.apply(lambda x: cols[x], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
df.assign(criteria=df.apply(lambda x: list(
    df.columns[1:][x[1:] == True]), axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   index  bol_1  bol_2  bol_3        criteria
0      1   True  False  False         [bol_1]
1      2  False   True  False         [bol_2]
2      3   True   True  False  [bol_1, bol_2]
```